# How to call stored procedure from OSB without using JDeveloper JCA adapter

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, osb

I need help on OSB 11g. I want to call stored procedure from OSB. I got so many answers which guide to develop JCA adopter through JDeveloper and configure in OSB. But I dont want to depend on JDeveloper every time. Can anybody suggest me is there any way we can call stored procedure without using JDeveloper JCA adopter.

Please note that its not executing simple sql query, its calling stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use  `fn-bea:execute-sql` function in `Xquery`. within it execute your procedure and assign in variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call Stored Procedure and don't want to use JCA, your best bet would be a Java Callout. Write a POJO to execute Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Using java callout is the best option , where you don't have to use jca files, for that matter , J-dev. Bea-execute-sql only works for select queries.